# How to create a lookup from list of lists using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

My input data is a **list** of lines like the one below, call it lines

> author1::author2::author3 - title

I created a function that extracts the authors and the title:

```
ExtractNameAndAuthors(string line, out string title, IList<string> authors)
```

I now want to create a lookup (ILookup) object using Linq in the form:

> key: title
>   value: list of authors

Anybody really fluent in Linq?

Comment: Create a small class with properties key,value and return it in `ExtractNameAndAuthors`. Then you can easily use it in Linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ generally doesn't play nice with `out` parameters.  You *can* do it, but it's generally best to avoid it.  Rather than passing data out through parameters it would be best to create a new type that holds onto the title as well as the list of authors so that `ExtractNameAndAuthors` can return an instance of that type:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string title, IList<string> authors)
    {
        Title = title;
        Authors = authors;
    }

    public string Title{get;private set;}
    public IList<string> Authors{get; private set;}
}
```

Once you have that, and have modified `ExtractNameAndAuthors` accordingly, you can do this:

```
var lookup = lines.Select(line => ExtractNameAndAuthors(line))
    .ToLookup(book => book.Title, book => book.Authors);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = new []{"author1::author2::author3 - title1",
                  "author1::author2::author3 - title2",};

var splited = list.Select(line => line.Split('-'));   

var result = splited
   .ToLookup(line => line[1], 
             line => line[0].Split(new[]{"::"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(string line)
    {
        this.Line = line;
    }

    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string[] Authors
    {
        get
        {
            return Line.Substring(0, Line.IndexOf("-") - 1).Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Line.Substring(Line.IndexOf("-") + 1);
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book("author1::author2::author3 - title1"),
        new Book("author1::author2 - title2")            
    };

    var auth3books = books.Where(b => b.Authors.Contains("author3"));
}
```